# Parametric equation for a circle centered at $(-5,-4)$ with a radius of $4$: Why is $t$ negative?

Tags: calculus, parametric, curves

The parametric equations for $x$ & $y$ are as follows:

$$x=-5+4 \cos (-t)$$

$$y=-4+4 \sin (-t)$$

My question is: Why is $t$ negative in this case?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is orientation. Using $(-5+4\cos(-t),-4+4\sin(-t))$ makes the circle go around clockwise, and $(-5+4\cos t,-4+4\sin t)$ makes it go counterclockwise. And when given a parametrization, it is important to give the domain too, for example, $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$. It is clear what you meant by "negative $t$", but having a $-$ sign does not mean that you must have $t < 0$.